# MS Graph subscription (/me/chats/getAllMessages) stop working

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We're using MS graph subscriptions to get notified on new teams messages for a user. We then get notifications *for some time*. We can decrypt the encrypted payload and get the message content. We also reauthorize the subscription on the corresponding lifecycle event (reauthorizationRequired). After a while we do no longer receive lifecycle events and in turn the subscription expires and we do not get any more teams messages. I do not see any error in the logs. **I need some advice what is wrong here.**

Here's how we register the subscription (header includes "Authorization: Bearer user-token")

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
    changeType: "created,updated",
    notificationUrl: `${host}/teams/notification`,
    lifecycleNotificationUrl: `${host}/teams/notification`,
    resource: "/me/chats/getAllMessages?model=B",
    includeResourceData: true,
    encryptionCertificate: "<base64 encoded cert>",
    encryptionCertificateId: "testcert1",
    expirationDateTime: <2160 minutes (1.5 days) from now>
}
```

The endpoint /teams/notification also returns the validationToken if the query parameter is set, after the subscription is created.

The lifecycle event reauthorizationRequired is handled by extending the subscription with the following request (header includes "Authorization: Bearer user-token").

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>
{
    expirationDateTime: <2160 minutes (1.5 days) from time of lifecycle event>
}
```

Can anyone spot an error or what is wrong here?

Used resources:

- [Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions)
- [Update subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/subscription-update)
- [Reduce missing subscriptions and change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/change-notifications-lifecycle-events)

Logfile from the last couple of days. Pretty strange things in between...

```
Feb 16, 2024 @ 08:51:29.979 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 6aa1a8af-64c5-4342-8fed-1aeea88c9893
Feb 16, 2024 @ 08:51:35.715 -> User-Login, subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e created (expires: 2024-02-17T19:51:29.779Z)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 09:09:15.544 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 09:53:39.720 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 47841e5a-2c47-46e3-8d99-27ffbe8f90c7
Feb 16, 2024 @ 09:53:45.019 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 10:49:33.159 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 10:50:37.751 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 10:50:52.567 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 10:55:53.315 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: db18caf3-6409-4d15-aee7-5b8ad81f0861
Feb 16, 2024 @ 10:55:58.682 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:04:14.790 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 00af1e45-9348-49d0-ae0c-56a21643474f
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:04:20.164 -> User-Login, subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e extended (expires: 2024-02-17T22:04:14.633Z)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:04:39.939 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:07:26.290 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:08:53.857 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:09:21.935 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:09:39.253 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:28:00.166 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:28:07.390 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 11:28:16.599 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 12:14:55.916 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 741dd0b9-a9c4-46d7-863d-4a8999793417
Feb 16, 2024 @ 12:15:01.155 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 12:56:04.925 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:03:10.843 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:05:31.635 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:06:21.995 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:06:33.035 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:09:29.204 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:11:26.775 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:26:07.557 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: b8d128c8-713c-4fd6-9b4f-7941ee7be9d3
Feb 16, 2024 @ 13:26:12.831 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 14:40:30.070 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: ba5294e3-17a6-49a3-a603-ddefbf460bc1
Feb 16, 2024 @ 14:40:35.404 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:08:56.521 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:10:32.933 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:13:32.417 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:33:39.740 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:34:35.437 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:36:15.222 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:36:28.414 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:36:37.275 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:39:17.787 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:39:47.850 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:40:33.015 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:42:39.311 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:42:42.620 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:42:44.949 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:42:50.987 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:43:46.356 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 9e767893-c7dd-4a74-a58c-45dd11d12ca5
Feb 16, 2024 @ 15:43:51.770 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 16:12:20.574 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 16:21:09.681 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 16:33:31.294 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 16:46:56.748 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: e9bcfb88-809a-4e59-a4d4-5b2ca0375757
Feb 16, 2024 @ 16:47:02.085 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:11:12.032 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:13:44.219 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:15:36.257 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:15:55.565 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:41:41.487 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 17:41:55.424 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 18:02:03.313 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: fa7528a1-9196-4c04-ba15-cdc2cc22a60c
Feb 16, 2024 @ 18:02:08.626 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 18:09:16.295 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 18:31:47.463 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 18:32:54.741 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 19:01:09.724 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 4d7aa15c-ec72-4b0b-9af1-93c62aa7da7f
Feb 16, 2024 @ 19:01:15.000 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 20:16:16.172 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 6da13d8b-3ddc-44ed-91f9-fa85a7c3d9bc
Feb 16, 2024 @ 20:16:21.381 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 21:31:22.175 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: b7226a11-4fdb-40fc-be40-442904d02887
Feb 16, 2024 @ 21:31:27.526 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 22:27:28.541 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 087ecf40-4b4f-4621-b747-63b380684cfb
Feb 16, 2024 @ 22:27:33.708 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 16, 2024 @ 23:32:34.521 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 648faf77-2498-4526-b7fc-1cbdc5cd1cdd
Feb 16, 2024 @ 23:32:39.948 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 00:37:41.197 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 32741b3b-5e1c-4630-ab3e-627d9ec647b7
Feb 17, 2024 @ 00:37:46.497 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 01:41:48.284 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: be98296c-1ad8-4acd-ae9b-318ede4ca3f4
Feb 17, 2024 @ 01:41:53.682 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 02:45:55.120 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: e42f8deb-5d92-4031-9756-afe9f02a0083
Feb 17, 2024 @ 02:46:00.445 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 03:52:01.461 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 9f8c1d78-bcfd-4b60-97b7-235266895618
Feb 17, 2024 @ 03:52:06.673 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 04:58:07.601 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: e3b3509c-4205-4f86-a255-2c39abba80d2
Feb 17, 2024 @ 04:58:12.798 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 05:49:13.465 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: e6379fc7-a620-4900-b5f0-efcebd424c83
Feb 17, 2024 @ 05:49:18.740 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 06:40:20.040 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: a6f53361-685a-4476-800c-9608331d8e3f
Feb 17, 2024 @ 06:40:25.253 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 07:43:26.260 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 0f281119-ac0b-4c97-a89e-fa3e95d314b5
Feb 17, 2024 @ 07:43:31.576 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 08:46:33.364 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: ef3576b8-6769-4938-888b-42c65ff6804b
Feb 17, 2024 @ 08:46:38.640 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 09:48:39.448 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 79d7ee36-c80d-40eb-a296-0840c64db0fb
Feb 17, 2024 @ 09:48:44.667 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 10:50:45.735 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: c1f1c5fb-4169-4f84-86a3-e004d252576a
Feb 17, 2024 @ 10:50:51.016 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 11:50:52.021 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 73b404bd-c3d8-4580-b34d-029016eeb54c
Feb 17, 2024 @ 11:50:57.275 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 12:50:58.434 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 49362b5e-eb9b-4fbb-8a84-b60977139e08
Feb 17, 2024 @ 12:51:03.799 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 14:07:04.750 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: af2b3a6c-476b-4242-b9a3-8ee3e653ac75
Feb 17, 2024 @ 14:07:10.011 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 15:23:11.420 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 67226fb5-28c3-4f64-870b-139e5afcdbde
Feb 17, 2024 @ 15:23:16.750 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 16:22:23.261 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 17:21:24.440 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: a32e2a84-34aa-401a-8936-edd31a7f8634
Feb 17, 2024 @ 17:21:29.677 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 18:25:30.761 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 9b832041-8e37-4787-81c4-fd5ef88802c5
Feb 17, 2024 @ 18:25:36.030 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 19:29:37.548 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: c5d7db98-3dd8-4266-bf7a-76b3cadbfd42
Feb 17, 2024 @ 19:29:42.874 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 20:29:44.037 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 1a8c6b49-dfe3-441f-8106-504b82176b30
Feb 17, 2024 @ 20:29:49.391 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 21:29:50.656 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 1bf61439-3a7b-46f2-9933-7070ec90cdaf
Feb 17, 2024 @ 21:29:55.837 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 17, 2024 @ 22:46:56.965 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 86ec4fc4-72db-49bf-bf06-1855fc39f92e
Feb 17, 2024 @ 22:47:02.286 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 00:04:03.499 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 0a9d364d-6429-4741-aac4-7c8661e7c92d
Feb 18, 2024 @ 00:04:08.805 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 01:16:09.944 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 7b9e13e8-4a61-4779-a6f1-3ec311b51a3c
Feb 18, 2024 @ 01:16:15.254 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 02:28:16.375 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 3059e376-3f4f-4c5d-829d-428f1a1a35ce
Feb 18, 2024 @ 02:28:21.614 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 03:34:22.587 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: f383b196-c127-41d8-a77c-a5299cb8b3fc
Feb 18, 2024 @ 03:34:27.804 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 04:40:29.243 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: d1a664ca-362a-427f-9db3-4f8f0328d48e
Feb 18, 2024 @ 04:40:34.468 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 05:51:35.604 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: b7dc3138-e29a-45a6-8982-b1012e692898
Feb 18, 2024 @ 05:51:40.913 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 07:02:46.943 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 07:53:52.960 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 08:44:59.087 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 10:02:08.642 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 1646ea21-de5a-4dad-85cf-9cb791574262
Feb 18, 2024 @ 10:02:13.958 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 11:19:14.928 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: d01a8dc2-e1c1-4a96-af5c-3305304aa6fb
Feb 18, 2024 @ 11:19:20.211 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 12:16:21.238 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 5ed1582b-a0df-4897-84eb-a43d373a5acd
Feb 18, 2024 @ 12:16:26.580 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 13:13:28.066 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 7be9cc41-1811-4502-88f4-2b7447acbc37
Feb 18, 2024 @ 13:13:33.293 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 14:14:34.429 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 1551b1ef-11b4-4036-84f8-a33dc23c39ab
Feb 18, 2024 @ 14:14:39.667 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 15:15:46.084 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 16:12:46.872 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: a8971a7d-b4bd-49b9-8087-25b7fab741e6
Feb 18, 2024 @ 16:12:52.072 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 17:09:53.078 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: cfc3bd8d-33da-4656-ac1f-433983bbc624
Feb 18, 2024 @ 17:09:58.306 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 18:09:59.270 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 17882c02-acc4-4675-abef-daf096058868
Feb 18, 2024 @ 18:10:04.624 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 19:10:10.787 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 20:09:11.972 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: c45d3eeb-1ea4-4ab0-baa3-468b6bd4cc28
Feb 18, 2024 @ 20:09:17.309 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 21:08:18.602 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 53436f09-c4b6-408c-8273-58bfadfba667
Feb 18, 2024 @ 21:08:23.770 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 22:04:24.808 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 5549ac06-60c3-4f1f-a2a5-586239612ebc
Feb 18, 2024 @ 22:04:30.215 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 18, 2024 @ 23:00:31.355 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 8ee7aea9-3d04-4288-8c75-6aa19be32e9a
Feb 18, 2024 @ 23:00:36.655 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 00:09:37.649 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 01fce1f8-e50a-4ed5-b03b-9051d346ce18
Feb 19, 2024 @ 00:09:42.976 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 01:18:48.995 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 02:32:49.884 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 4daa3210-a9e9-485e-9304-f4b09d7ec139
Feb 19, 2024 @ 02:32:55.074 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 03:47:01.871 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 04:46:02.703 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: d4be8f69-60bf-4ab4-9353-8149d3d9319a
Feb 19, 2024 @ 04:46:07.992 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 05:45:09.152 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: dbb8632e-d8b5-4e2f-bca4-3f84562daba5
Feb 19, 2024 @ 05:45:14.409 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 06:46:15.280 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 6b710aef-7bfe-459b-92a0-25c46a201731
Feb 19, 2024 @ 06:46:20.522 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 07:46:22.259 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 00915d75-f449-422e-a82f-a46da9c04c30
Feb 19, 2024 @ 07:46:27.576 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 08:42:47.260 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 09:39:01.159 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 09:54:26.207 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 09:54:41.033 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 09:54:52.006 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 09:57:44.860 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:01:50.951 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:02:17.634 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:06:26.914 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:09:09.978 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:54:18.601 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 26c653d4-cb30-42c1-bd04-70f55bafb7a5
Feb 19, 2024 @ 10:54:23.815 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 11:27:26.053 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:15:22.241 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 3a2e5fc4-386d-482a-bd0e-1026cb739434
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:15:27.626 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:26:56.309 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:28:51.040 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:33:24.105 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:33:59.533 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:56:46.876 -> Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: e8d08c62-e6cf-4052-8f58-1c867cddf9f6
Feb 19, 2024 @ 12:56:52.246 -> User-Login, subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e extended (expires: 2024-02-21T20:42:07.657Z)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 13:45:52.193 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 13:47:23.984 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 19, 2024 @ 13:47:40.500 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
==>> no more lifecycle events even though the subscription is still active (missing Teams messages in this timeframe)
==>> there are Teams messages between 09:03 and 09:42
==>> they are delivered later on after the User-Login with subscriptions extension
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:42:12.920 -> User-Login, subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e extended (expires: 2024-02-21T20:42:07.657Z)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:44:35.085 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:47:28.741 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:30)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:48:09.227 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:38)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:49:14.574 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:31)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:49:35.550 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:31)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:50:17.553 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:20)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:50:29.549 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:51:00.005 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:52:01.726 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:52:10.006 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:57:30.690 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:03)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:59:13.091 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:40)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 09:59:23.853 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:03)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 10:00:02.229 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:36)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 10:00:24.652 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 09:41)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 10:18:59.944 -> Teams Message Notification (received but message is from 08:29)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:03:16.735 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:25:58.451 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:27:15.912 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:28:12.869 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:33:38.939 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:37:48.353 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:38:13.565 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:38:42.891 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:39:06.057 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:41:48.216 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 11:42:16.952 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:25:50.542 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:26:47.909 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:26:53.408 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:27:29.556 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:28:07.129 -> Lifecycle Event reauthorizationRequired for subscription 66cb4656-1f89-4978-9f8b-eddaa10a182e (extended by 2160 minutes)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:28:11.111 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
Feb 20, 2024 @ 12:28:33.909 -> Teams Message Notification (received)
==>> no more lifecycle events even though the subscription is still active (missing Teams messages in this timeframe)
==>> there are some messages sent around 14:00-14:10 but they are missing
==>> even tough there are successful reauthorization event, no validationToken is sent
```

Comment: The resource subscription steps are correct. Could you please check the logs to see if there are any errors or issues that could be causing the problem?

Comment: Do you mean my application logs? I already did and there is nothing related to this. Are there any logs on the Azure side that I can check?

Comment: I added some logs from the last couple of days. Especially yesterday and today is a gap in notifications. Yesterday the notifications where sent after the user logged in and in turn extended his current subscription. The order of messages was totally messed up (And from the docs I would not suspect the messaged to be delivered like that much later). Today there are again missing notification and they're not delivered because the user did not log in (but the subscription should still be active...)